# what is the use of [Datacontract] attribute in entity class of WCF

Tags: wcf, datacontracts

I am using .net 4.0 and wcf service. I have business entity classes which is not defined with `[Datacontract]` attribute.

When I try to retrieve less than 1000 records of type business entity class it works fine
but when I try retrieving more than 1000 records of type business entity class, it throws this exception:

> *The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:Securities. The InnerException message was
>   'Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an
>   object graph is '65536'. Change the object graph or increase the
>   MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota. '.  Please see InnerException for more
>   details.*

The problem got solved, when using the `[DataContract]` attribute defined for the business entity class.

1. so what importance does the `[DataContract]` attribute play in the above case?
2. what is the difference between using a business entity class defined with `[DataContract]` attribute and without `[DataContract]` attribute?

Comment: Are you able to retrieve all the data from various properties that you need after specifying the [DataContract] attribute on your entity objects.

Answer (score 7):

By applying `[DataContract]` to a class, you are telling WCF that you will be explicitly declaring which properties are to be serialized by the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx).

By default, without `[DataContract]`, DCS will serialize all public properties, e.g. given the below, if you serialize an instance of House, Window and Door will also be fully serialized.

```
public class Window
{
  public string Colour {get; set;}
  public bool IsClean {get; set; }
}


public class Door
{
  public string Colour {get; set;}
  public bool IsOpen {get; set; }
}


public class House
{
  public Door Door {get; set;}
  public Window Window {get; set; }
}
```

By Comparison, if you specify `[DataContract]` on House, then only members with the `[DataMember]` attribute will be serialized, viz in the case below, only the Address property of House will be serialized:

```
[DataContract]
public class House
{
  [DataMember]
  public string Address {get; set;}

  // Omitted DataMember!
  public Door Door {get; set;}
  public Window Window {get; set; }
}
```

I'm guessing the reason why adding `[DataContract]` works in your case is *probably* because you've add it to the root entity, but somewhere down the entity graph "chain", one or more of the composited entities don't have the `[DataMember]` attribute. If you've just marked your root entity as `[DataContract]` with no `[DataMember]`s then only the root entity is serialized, thus avoiding the `MaxItemsInGraph` setting (but your clients obviously won't receive any of the unserialized entities).

Comment: All my properties in the class are public.and when i use the class without [Datacontract] attribute ,when i try to retreive more than 1000 records of the class type,it throws exception.but it works when i retreive less than 1000 records.what role does [datcontract] plays when retreiving less record and more than 1000 records...

Comment: @subash - You need to check through all your classes, applying [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes to classes and Properties that you DO want to be serialized (and thus appear to clients of your WCF service)